# Ubuntu boost b2 error: Cannot use --layout=system with --build-type complete

Tags: ubuntu, boost, build, libraries

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with gcc 4.6.3. I have downloaded the last boost_1_55_0.tar.gz, unzipped it in `usr/local/boost_155` folder, created environment variable `BOOST_ROOT` and `executed ./bootstrap.sh`.  Then I tryed to run:

```
sudo ./b2 --toolset=gcc --build-type=complete --with-date_time --with-thread --with-system --with-chrono stage
```

The same actions works good under XP with MinGW 4.8.0, and with msvc-9.0-10.0:
`b2.exe --toolset=gcc-4.8.0 --build-type=complete --with-date_time --with-thread --with-system --with-chrono architecture=x86 address-model=32 stage`
But under Ubuntu b2 refuses to work, giving me the following errors:

```
error: Cannot use --layout=system with --build-type complete.
error: Please use either --layout=versioned or --layout=tagged
error: if you wish to build multiple variants.
error: Note that --layout=system is used by default on Unix starting with Boost 1.40.
```

I don't want to build all boost. I need now boost::thread only;
How it must be done under Ubuntu?
Did somebody have installed boost_1_54 or (already) boost_1_55 by similar way? Where I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried installing boost-devel through your package manager?

Comment: @Sam Miller No. I from very beginning wanted to use the last boost version. Months ago I have  installed Eclipse with CDT tools, Qt 5.1.0 (32 bit) and some libraries for VLC and Audacity. Could some of them be incompatible with boost::b2? Does <apt-get install libboost-all-dev>  is the only one workable way to install it? (but older boost version )

Comment: [solution] It turns out that error message contained solution of this problem. The command line must look like this: sudo ./b2 --toolset=gcc --build-type=complete --layout=versioned --with-date_time --with-thread --with-system --with-chrono stage

Answer (score 0):

The command line must look like this:

```
sudo ./b2 --toolset=gcc --build-type=complete --layout=versioned --with-date_time --with-thread --with-system --with-chrono stage
```